# How can I change div HTML tag via button onclick event using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="...">
    <div class="container" id="main_container" style="margin-top: -80px">
        <div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-2" style="background-color: #f8f8f8;text-align: center;"><a href="http://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/{{ id6 }}" target="_blank">{{ id6 }}</a></div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-1" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ rating6 }}</div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-6" style="background-color: #F8F8F8"><marquee scrollamount="4">{{ description6 }}</marquee></div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-3" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ date6 }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-2" style="background-color: #f8f8f8;text-align: center;"><a href="http://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/{{ id7 }}" target="_blank">{{ id7 }}</a></div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-1" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ rating7 }}</div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-6" style="background-color: #F8F8F8"><marquee scrollamount="4">{{ description7 }}</marquee></div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-3" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ date7 }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px">
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-5">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-2" align="center">
                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" type="button" id="my_button">History</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-5"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px">
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-2" style="background-color: #f8f8f8;text-align: center;"><a href="http://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/{{ id8 }}" target="_blank">{{ id8 }}</a></div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-1" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ rating8 }}</div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-6" style="background-color: #F8F8F8"><marquee scrollamount="4">{{ description8 }}</marquee></div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-3" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ date8 }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I have a simple header HTML div structure with button `id="my_button"`. On button event onclick the first div tag with `id="main_container"` should change css directives, in particular margin-top value from `-80px` to `0px` and when margin-top value equals `0px` it should be changed to `-80px`.

I'm new in web development. I guess I need a javascript script function with `OnClick` event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-you should add the margin's into the div using style="margin:xxx%"

You can use this javascript code to make it change when the button is clicked:

```
function MoveDiv() {
    var e = document.getElementById("YOUR_DIV_id");
    if (e.style.marginTop == '-80px')
    {
        e.style.marginTop = "0px";
    }
    else 
    {
        e.style.marginTop = "-80px";
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call it with an OnClick function into a button, something like this: `<button onClick="MoveDiv()">Click me</button>`

Answer (score 2):

use below function for change margin-top by using javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#my_button').click(function() {
         var margin = $('#main_container').css('margin-top');
         var newMargin = (margin=='-80px')?'0px':'-80px';
         $('#main_container').css('margin-top',newMargin);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call a Javascript function on button click and validate the marginTop values.

**HTML**

```
  <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" type="button" id="my_button" onclick="test()">History</button>
```

**JS**

```
  function test() {
    var marginValue = document.getElementById('main_container').style.marginTop;
    if(marginValue == "-80px") {
      document.getElementById('main_container').style.marginTop = "0px";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('main_container').style.marginTop = "-80px";
    }
   }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/tcw4rxhz/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var button = document.querySelector("#my_button");
var container = document.querySelector("#main_container");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  container.style.marginTop = "0px"
})
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="...">
    <div class="container" id="main_container" style="margin-top: -80px">
        <div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-2" style="background-color: #f8f8f8;text-align: center;"><a href="http://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/{{ id6 }}" target="_blank">{{ id6 }}</a></div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-1" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ rating6 }}</div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-6" style="background-color: #F8F8F8"><marquee scrollamount="4">{{ description6 }}</marquee></div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-3" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ date6 }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-2" style="background-color: #f8f8f8;text-align: center;"><a href="http://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/{{ id7 }}" target="_blank">{{ id7 }}</a></div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-1" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ rating7 }}</div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-6" style="background-color: #F8F8F8"><marquee scrollamount="4">{{ description7 }}</marquee></div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-3" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ date7 }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px">
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-5">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-2" align="center">
                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" type="button" id="my_button">History</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-5"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px">
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-2" style="background-color: #f8f8f8;text-align: center;"><a href="http://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/{{ id8 }}" target="_blank">{{ id8 }}</a></div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-1" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ rating8 }}</div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-6" style="background-color: #F8F8F8"><marquee scrollamount="4">{{ description8 }}</marquee></div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-3" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ date8 }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

But I recommend to use `transform` for better perfomance. For example:

Before: `transform: translateY(-80px)`.
After: `transform: translateY(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code, I removed your inline style and added css class:

```
<style>
#main_container { margin-top:0;}
#main_container.margin_top { margin-top:-80px;}
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="...">
<div class="container" id="main_container">
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-2" style="background-color: #f8f8f8;text-align: center;"><a href="http://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/{{ id6 }}" target="_blank">{{ id6 }}</a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-1" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ rating6 }}</div>
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-6" style="background-color: #F8F8F8"><marquee scrollamount="4">{{ description6 }}</marquee></div>
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-3" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ date6 }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-2" style="background-color: #f8f8f8;text-align: center;"><a href="http://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/{{ id7 }}" target="_blank">{{ id7 }}</a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-1" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ rating7 }}</div>
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-6" style="background-color: #F8F8F8"><marquee scrollamount="4">{{ description7 }}</marquee></div>
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-3" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ date7 }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px">
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-5">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-2" align="center">
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" type="button" id="my_button">History</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-5"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px">
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-2" style="background-color: #f8f8f8;text-align: center;"><a href="http://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/{{ id8 }}" target="_blank">{{ id8 }}</a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-1" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ rating8 }}</div>
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-6" style="background-color: #F8F8F8"><marquee scrollamount="4">{{ description8 }}</marquee></div>
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-3" style="background-color: #f5f4f5;text-align: center;">{{ date8 }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>

<script>
var button = document.getElementById('my_button');
var container = document.getElementById('main_container');
button.onclick = function(){
    container.classList.toggle("margin_top");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeMargin() {
   var button = document.getElementById("my_button");
   var container = document.getElementById("main_container");

   button.addEventListener("click", function () {
         if (container.style.marginTop == '-80px') {
            container.style.marginTop = "0px";
         } else 
         {
            container.style.marginTop = "-80px";
         }
   });
}
 
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
   changeMargin();
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).